# String.Empty or null: what is better to return for "Error" field from service?

Tags: c#, .net, string

We all know (more or less) about difference between String.Empty and null. I still didn't decided what is better for me in "usual" development (I mean development of server side part of ASP.NET application, WinForms application - everything that is C#.NET code), but I saw and read a lot of articles about.

But I didn't see comparison what is better to use when you are returning string values from the services (ASP.NET WebService or WCF service).

What is your suggestion should I return null or String.Empty:

1. When I need to return 'Error' message (null or empty will mean 'there are no errors');
2. When I need to return 'Email' field value (null or empty will mean 'email was not specified).

Any thoughts are welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is all a matter of taste, style and consistency. Do you have other services that return null/empty already? If so, it's best to match them. Otherwise in my personal opinion null is better than empty. As null serves as a better sentinel value. An empty string could be perceived as an error did occur but no error details were returned.

Comment: This is a good point: An empty string could be perceived as an error did occur but no error details were returned. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Generally I would use whichever return value is more consistent with how the rest of your code handles this situation. The cases you described could certainly go either way; in my opinion, the Error message returning null when no error is present makes more sense, while the Email makes more sense as an empty string (since the Email was not entered/specified).

Answer (score 0):

Always return `string.Empty` instead of `null`.

Then the code that uses the service method will not have to bother about `NullReferenceException` if they invoke an operation on string returned by your service.

Recurring null checks make your code look ugly and difficult to read.

Comment: Defensive coding would suggest you check the return value for null anyway.

Comment: Agree with you in some way, but my point is another: they should check instance 'if it is not null' before call its methods... Though, there is a special pattern for such cases 'DefaultObject'

Answer (score 0):

NULL and string.empty is represented the same way in the pure request form. The difference is the XSD mapping, in regards to setting nillable="true" or not.

A better request is probably to return a "Invalid" result, so that it cannot be misunderstood by any 3rd part consumers of your service.

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, Null represents an undefined value.  For this argument's sake, let's say you have a flag that indicates whether a user has an email address or not.  If this flag is not set, Null would be the appropriate value for an Email address.  If the flag is set, the empty string would indicate that no email address was supplied.

With an error message, I would again say that Null represents undefined, e.g. there is no error to report.  The empty string might indicate that an error occurred but for some reason the detail has not been provided.

As long as you are consistent within your service, though, either should be fine.